# Random XML Questions Using Fisher-Yates Shuffle

Tags: c#, shuffle

I am making a Quiz/Trivia Game and have questions stored in XML file and it gets a random question. Everything works fine, but I want to stay random but not show the same question until every question has been shown.

```
 public struct Question {
 public string questionText;
 public string answerA;
 public string answerB;
 public string answerC;
 public string answerD;
 public int correctAnswerID;
 }

[XmlRoot("QuestionsRoot")]
public class QuestionData {
[XmlArray("Questions")]
[XmlArrayItem("Question")]
public List<Question>questions = new List<Question>();

 public static QuestionData LoadFromText(string text) {
 try {
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QuestionData));            
     return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as QuestionData;
 } catch (Exception e) {
     UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Exception loading question data: " + e);
     return null;
 }
}
```

And I use this in my other script to get a random question:

```
 questionData = QuestionData.LoadFromText(questionDataXMLFile.text)
 q = Random.Range(0, questionData.questions.Count);
 currentQuestion = questionData.questions[q];
```

Comment: If you're asking how to implement fisher-yates, there are plenty of examples on this site, and wikipedia. If you have actually tried implementing it, we need to see that code, and you need to explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I tried with

          for (int i = 1; i < questionData.questions.Count; i++) {
   int pos = random.Next(i + 1);
   string x = questionData.questions[i];
   questionData.questions[i] =                        questionData.questions[pos];
   questionData.questions[pos] = x;
  }

But the problem is that it cannot convert type "Question" to string

Comment: So use `Question x` instead of `string x`.

Comment: Also, why not post that code and the error in the original post? You need to explain your actual problem in order to get help. Note that you can [edit] your post!

Comment: Ok, I will. Thank you

Comment: It removed the errors. I cant believe I didn't think of that earlier ! Thanks so much. Do you know how can I get the question ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "get the question"?

Comment: As far as I understand the shuffle method is run once and from then how can I set new question from the array ?

Comment: `var newQuestion = questions[0]; questions.RemoveAt(0);` Check `questions.Any()` is true before you do it, so you know when you run out of questions.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Hi again. Sorry to bother you but can you help me with one last thing. I changes the code and need little help. Lets say I have 10 questions. I want them to be randomly picked and not repeat until all 10 of them have been shown. Here is my code:

for (i = 1; i < questionData.questions.Count; i++) {
   r = Random.Range(0, i);
   tmp = questionData.questions[i];
   questionData.questions[i] = questionData.questions[r];
   questionData.questions[r] = tmp;

I don't know what to do when calling a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Do something along the following lines:

create another list with available questions - initialise it to the list of all questions:

```
 questionData = QuestionData.LoadFromText(questionDataXMLFile.text)

 var available = new List<Question>(questionData.question);
 ...
 }

 public Question GetNextQuestion()
 {
     if (available.Count == 0)
        available.AddRange(questionData.question);

    q = Random.Range(0, available.Count);
    currentQuestion = available[q];
    available.RemoveAt(q);

    return currentQuestion;
 }
```

Comment: Op mentions shuffle, which this isn't. Will still work, though.